# Vuejs + Laravel скачать файл (axios)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Пытаюсь скачать файл размером 150mb на стеке Laravel + Vue с использованием axios:
На фронте: axios который по клику обращается к методу на бэке в котором return Storage::disk('ftp')->download($filename);
Само скачивание проходит на ура, но есть загвоздка:
1. Пользователь нажимает на ссылку, после этого достучавшись до ftp файл записывается в память, т.к. он весит 150mb все это дело происходит относительно долго. Пользователь не понимает что происходит, т.к. никаких очевидных действий не происходит для него.
2. Как только файл полностью записан в память, выскакивает окно с предложением сохранить файл на ПК.

Что я хочу:
1. Пользователь нажимает на ссылку, после этого сразу выскакивает окно с предложением сохранить файл на пк (без записи его в буфер), и после выбора директории, файл начинает скачиваться в браузере (внизу появляется файл с круглым прогресс баром, как например в Chrome).

Есть также другое приложение на Laravel, там на фронте не используется Vue, соответственно по нажатию на ссылку, файл начинает скачиваться, так как я хочу (с прогресс баром и т.п.).

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но видимо из-за недостатка знаний решить проблему не получается, сижу уже второй день, если кто-то поможет идеей буду очень благодарен. Laravel 5.7, php 7.1.3.

Comment: Открывай ссылку в новом окне без использования axios и там браузер уже разберётся. Сейчас axios дожидается пока запрос завершится.

Answer (score 0):

Использование axios тут избыточно.
Просто ставь html-ссылку, не обязательно с `target="_blank"`, на метод, который делает `return Storage::disk('ftp')->download($filename);` . Laravel помещает в хедеры информацию, что это скачивание файла, а браузер это понимает и не изменяет текущую страницу с vue-приложением.